# Is it possible to use のが twice in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-の, particle-が

I'm doing a project for my Japanese class and I'm trying to write the question "I enjoy learning about Japan." And the only way I can think to do that is 「私は日本を学ぶのがするのが楽しいです。」 is that possible or is there another way to say that phrase that I'm not understanding?

Comment: What do you intend to mean by 学ぶのがする?  学ぶ is already a verb meaning to study.

Comment: のがするのが is a useless pleonasm that reduces to のが.  Xを学ぶのがたのしいです. There exist verbose constructions with ことが, like Xすることができない, instead of just Xできない. I don't think I've heard pile-ups of のが.

Comment: "learn **about** Japan" should be 「日本について学ぶ」or 「日本のことを学ぶ」. `日本を学ぶ` is like saying "learn Japan". `I'm trying to write the question "I enjoy learning about Japan."` <- "I enjoy learning about Japan" is not a question.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but "I enjoy learning about Japan." is

> 私は日本**について**学ぶのが<del>するのが</del>楽しいです

It has really nothing to do with using のが twice. As pointed out in the comment, 学ぶ is a verb, which is nominalized by の, so that 学ぶのが means *Learning (something) is*.

A minor point is that generally you use better について for *about*.

---

のが can appear twice, e.g. if you a nominalized clause. A bit contrived example is:

> 日本語を学ぶの<sup>1</sup>が難しいの<sup>2</sup>が、日本人である自分にはよくわからない
>
> I, being a Japanese, do not quite understand that learning Japanese is difficult.

の<sup>1</sup> works as a nominalizer for *to learn* (i.e., like *ing*) and の<sup>2</sup> as a nominalizer for the clause 日本語..難しい (i.e., *that* in English).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cascading のが onto the same clause, we can think about relativizing two clauses, each of which have a が subject marker: AがBがC, such that both of the が are applied to some verb phrase nominalized by の: AのがBのがC.

How about:

> 試験を合格する**のが**楽だった**のが**よかった。Shiken-o gōkaku-suru no ga raku datta no ga yokatta. (That it had been easy to pass the exam was a relief.)

In the sentence 私は日本を学ぶのがするのが楽しいです the のがするのが is just a pleonasm that shortens to のが. I.e. は日本を学ぶのが楽しいです。I don't recall having heard or read such a のが pile up, for what it's worth. Some verbosities involving the ことが nominalization are fairly often heard, like Xすることができない instead of simply Xできない, where X takes する.

Comment: 「試験**を**合格する」→「試験**に**合格する」がいいですね。